# Cannot access my Django project from LAN

Tags: python, django

Locally I can access the python project using `127.0.0.1:8000`. 
I want to access it via LAN as well. I've done some research how to figure it out and I've followed these steps:

in the `settings.py` file I did `ALLOWED_HOSTS=[192.168.1.11:8000]`, that's my computer's LAN IP address. 
Then in the terminal I've done `python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.11:8000`, it didn't work and I've tried to replace the IP address with `0.0.0.0:8000` but the same issue occured.

With `DEBUG=True` I get the following error message:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header:'<my_ip_adress>'. 
You may need to add '<my_ip_adress>' to ALLOWED_HOSTS,
```

and I've already done this...

Comment: convert ALLOWED_HOSTS=[192.168.1.11:8000] to ALLOWED_HOSTS=['192.168.1.11']

Comment: bro it doesnt matter from lan or wifi you are using it. you are accessing the django in your machine means its localhost. so 127.0.0.1 is the one you need to allow

Comment: Thanks Mohammad,now it's okay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure your [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) variable correct:

- It must be a list of strings, representing the allowed hosts without defining the ports.
- It must include every and any possible host that you want to allow.

So you need to:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '192.168.1.11',
    '127.0.0.1', # This is the one you need to allow in your case
]
```

Finally as @cezar points out, you need to run the server at `0.0.0.0:8000` in order to "broadcast" it on your LAN:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to make it accessible for test purposes in the Local Area Network, then run:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

In your `settings.py` an empty list for allowed hosts should be enough:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal/command promt type

```
ifconfig #for linux

ipconfig #for windows
```

You will get the information about the network connection and you will find your IP. Take that IP and run as

```
python manage.py runserver <your-ip>
```

in django ***settings.py***

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

Now you can connect this server throughout any device connected to the same network.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Ubuntu 19.10

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 8000 proto tcp
```

I've also have to enable packet forwarding in */etc/sysctl.conf* and delete the *#* prepended to `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`.
Finally, I've cleared the browser cache.

Previously I was on Mint 19.03 and I only had to add the *ufw* rule.